# "cannot move out of borrowed content" when using skip_while()

Tags: rust

I have trouble using a `std::iter::Peekable`. Why does the following code does not compile?

```
// rustc 1.7.0-nightly (b4707ebca 2015-12-27)

use std::iter::*;

struct Foo<'a> {
    chars: Peekable<Chars<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   fn foo(&mut self) {
       self.chars.next(); // Ok
       self.chars.skip_while(|c| true); // error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[skip_while](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while) takes self by value. But `chars` can't be moved because it's still mutably borrowed by the `&mut self`. You can use [by_ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) to make sure the value skip_while gets is a reference to a wrapper, instead.

```
self.chars.by_ref().skip_while(|c| true);
```

Comment: Why do uncopyable structs ever implement methods that take `self` by value? Assuming it's reasonable to call other methods after it, that is...

Comment: @weberc2 skip_while is a method of Iterator, not an inherent method of Chars (so it could not have been implemented to take &self). In general, though, taking self by value does not prevent passing a reference instead (self becomes &self, &self is then passed by value). We do exactly this in this case, using the by_ref adapter.